# MongoDB: query multiple $elemmatch with $all

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my app, I have a **polls** collection and the a document looks like this;

```
/* POLLS */
{ 
...
  "type": "COMMON",
  "__v": {
    "$numberInt": "0"
  },
  "targets": [
    {
      "code": "city",
      "logic": "eq",
      "value": "4"
    },
    {
      "code": "city",
      "logic": "eq",
      "value": "15"
    }
  ]
}
```

And the targeting key is an array contains of objects of targets.
Each target's code can be **city** or **gender**. 
So it means, "gender" **may** not be found in a Poll document.

Depending on that when fetching **Polls**, I want the ones matching with my User's fields, if the code exists.

**For example;** When fetching the Polls from a User's feed, 
If a Poll contains **gender** targeting, I want to find polls matching with my User's gender.

My code is like this:

```
Poll.find({
        state: "PUBLISHED",
        approval: "APPROVED",
        $or: [
          {
            targets: {
              $exists: true,
              $eq: []
            }
          },
          {
            targets: {
              $exists: true,
              $ne: [],
              $all: [
                {
                  $elemMatch: {
                    code: {
                      $exists: true,
                      $eq: "city"
                    },
                    value: {
                      $eq: foundUser.cityCode // equals to 4 in this example
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  $elemMatch: {
                    code: {
                      $exists: true,
                      $eq: "gender"
                    },
                    value: {
                      $eq: foundUser.gender // equals to m in this example
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      })
```

**However**, 
the list returns empty for the Poll document I wrote above.

When the part below commented out, the code returns the correct polls.

```
Poll.find({
        state: "PUBLISHED",
        approval: "APPROVED",
        $or: [
          {
            targets: {
              $exists: true,
              $eq: []
            }
          },
          {
            targets: {
              $exists: true,
              $ne: [],
              $all: [
                {
                  $elemMatch: {
                    code: {
                      $exists: true,
                      $eq: "city"
                    },
                    value: {
                      $eq: foundUser.cityCode // equals to 4 in this example
                    }
                  }
                },
                // {
                //   $elemMatch: {
                //     code: {
                //       $exists: true,
                //       $eq: "gender"
                //     },
                //     value: {
                //       $eq: foundUser.gender // equals to m in this example
                //     }
                //   }
                // }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      })
```

May anyone help me with the situation that return the right polls when gender or country targeted? 
Thanks, **Onur.**

Comment: Please share collection

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar you can see at the top The Poll colleciton

Comment: Can you share at jsoneditor online ??

Comment: https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=ee103d8c1aba42eba15e6629adfc854e @MaheshBhatnagar

Answer (score 0):

Return targets field is an array whose elements match the $elemMatch criteria in array

Try that query

```
Poll.find({
        state: "PUBLISHED",
        approval: "APPROVED",
        $or: [
          {
            targets: {
              $exists: true,
              $eq: []
            }
          },
          {
            targets: {
              $exists: true,
              $ne: [],
              $all: [
                {
                  $elemMatch: {
                    code: {
                      $exists: true,
                      $eq: "city"
                    },
                    value: {
                      $eq: "4" // equals to 4 in this example
                    }
                  }
                }

              ]
            }
          },
          {
            targets: {
              $exists: true,
              $ne: [],
              $all: [

                {
                  $elemMatch: {
                    code: {
                      $exists: true,
                      $eq: "gender"
                    },
                    value: {
                      $eq: 'm' // equals to m in this example
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      })
```

Comment: Actually this way is not correct since it targets "my gender is m" or "my city is 4". I want to achieve  "my gender is m" AND "my city is 4". Any suggestions?

Comment: I want that If a Poll document contains target which contains "gender", I want to filter from found user gender, also if the same document contains "city" too, I want both check if the user's city and gender matches the condition.

Comment: Please share collection with what you want collection

Comment: https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=419662b263c44a729366dd80d3578602 This is the first possible option of Poll document. It contains both gender and city. In my case user has a gender as M and city as "6". So this should be a found document on the query. https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=079e4ba815b24dceb8345ab72c3fad46 This is other Poll object not contains gender